# Como fazer notificação através da barra de tarefas no c#?

Tags: c#, notificação

Para meu aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo estou criando um **ícone** que irá ficar na barra de tarefas para mostrar as **notificações para o usuário** e dentro dele o usuário terá opções como : **Sair,Abrir,Configurar** e etc,mas não tenho ideias de como fazer isto.

Eu consegui criar o ícone que irá ficar do lado dos ícones por exemplo do som e do wi-fi,mas ao minimizar o programa ele some da barra de tarefas e somente fica o ícone.

**Meu código :**

```
 private void FrmIntegracaoPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Minimizando aplicação na bandeja do windows */
            this.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Exibindo novamente o programa */
            this.Visible = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Visible = false;
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }

            //Verificando se WindowsState == Minimized
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                //CODIGO 
            }
        }
```

**Como posso fazer isto ?** Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um [ContextMenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e sua aplicação, e em seguida definir ele na propriedade `ContextMenuStrip` do [NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), veja neste exemplo:

```
// 
// notifyIcon
// 
this.notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info;
this.notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Notificação exemplo";
this.notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip;
this.notifyIcon.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon.Icon")));
this.notifyIcon.Text = "Aplicação";
this.notifyIcon.Visible = true;
// 
// contextMenuStrip
// 
this.contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.exibirToolStripMenuItem,
this.fecharToolStripMenuItem});
this.contextMenuStrip.Name = "contextMenuStrip";
this.contextMenuStrip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 70);
// 
// exibirToolStripMenuItem
// 
this.exibirToolStripMenuItem.Name = "exibirToolStripMenuItem";
this.exibirToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
this.exibirToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Exibir";
this.exibirToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.exibirToolStripMenuItem_Click);
// 
// fecharToolStripMenuItem
// 
this.fecharToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fecharToolStripMenuItem";
this.fecharToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
this.fecharToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Fechar";
this.fecharToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.fecharToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

Este menu tem duas opções, que são `Exibir` e `Fechar`, o código associado ao clique de cada uma e do formulário segue abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NotificacaoBarraTarefasExemplo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {                
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void exibirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void fecharToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode adicionar quantos menus quiser no `ContextMenuStrip`, o importante é que seu `ContextMenuStrip` esteja definido no `NotifyIcon`.

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx

Comment: Funcionou,muito obrigado,já dei +1 e também como resposta que ajudou no meu problema.

Comment: Mas como poderia fazer com que quando houver uma atualização ou mudanças nas configurações do aplicativo,apareça uma mensagem no ícone avisando o usuário?

Comment: @Falion [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373060/show-a-balloon-notification) você pode implementar usando o próprio NotifyIcon, se quiser algo mais personalizado tem esta [biblioteca](https://github.com/Tulpep/Notification-Popup-Window) que pode ajudar você.

Comment: Testei e não funcionou,ele não aparece do jeito que quero,aparecendo a mensagem com um balão saindo do ícone,ele some aparece a mensagem caso você coloque o cursor por cima do ícone.

Comment: A lib que postei aí, foi ela que vc testou?

Comment: Testei um outro código parecido e funcionou normalmente,obrigado :)